# Iteration of two identical Set using Java Streams

Tags: java-stream, iteration, java-9

I have two HashSets with same type of objects.  My search criteria is like, search in first set and if not present then search in another set.  I had tried with Stream layer with following steps as given below

```
Set<MyObject> firstSet = new HashSet<>();
Set<MyObject> secondSet = new HashSet<>();
```

and these two sets are having some values.

```
Predicate<MyObject> match = myObject -> StringUtils.equals(myValue, myObject.getMyValue());

firstSet.values().stream().filter(match).findFirst()
.orElse(secondSet.values().stream().filter(match)
.findFirst().orElseThrow(()-> new MyException()));
```

My matching object is in First Set and i have tried to get it by manually and i got it... but using the above iteration, i always get the exception even when the first set has the matched object.  Kindly correct me.. thanks is advance.

Comment: When you pass a parameter to a method, the parameter gets evaluated first. In the outer (i.e. first) orElse, the parameter to that orElse is `secondSet.stream().values().filter(match)
.findFirst().orElseThrow(()-> new MyException())`, which gets evaluated before anything else on the last three lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not using `Optional.orElse` as expected.

When you use `Optional.orElse`, its parameter is evaluated *eagerly*. This means that your second set is being searched first, to resolve the parameter of your first set's `Optional.orElse`.

Instead, use [`Optional.orElseGet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet-java.util.function.Supplier-), which receives a `Supplier` that is evaluated *lazily*:

```
firstSet.stream()
    .filter(match)
    .findFirst()
    .orElseGet(() -> secondSet.stream()
        .filter(match)
        .findFirst()
        .orElseThrow(()-> new MyException()));
```

---

**EDIT:** As suggested by Holger in the comments, there is an easier way:

```
Stream.of(firstSet, secondSet)
    .flatMap(Set::stream)
    .filter(match)
    .findFirst()
    .orElseThrow(MyException::new);
```

Streaming the sets first and then calling `flatMap` ensures that elements of the first set will all appear before elements of the second set.

Comment: thank you for your answer... i will try this now

Comment: this is working now.... thanks alot..

Comment: There is no `values()` method in a `Set`. Besides that, just `Stream.concat(firstSet.stream(), secondSet.stream()) .filter(match) .findFirst() .orElseThrow(MyException::new)` will do the job.

Comment: @Holger Fixed `.values()` thing, thanks. I thought in a code similar to yours, and if they were lists I would have done it that way. But they are sets. Are we 100% sure by the spec that, after  calling `Stream.concat` on two streams whose source are sets, elements from the second set will appear after all the elements of the first set?

Comment: Taking the spec as written, you can’t be sure. So, if you want to be on the safe side, you’d rather use `Stream.of(firstSet, secondSet) .flatMap(Set::stream) .filter(match) .findFirst() .orElseThrow(MyException::new)` which is guaranteed to be ordered as intended.